# Данные из формы не добавляются в бд

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

```
$login = $_POST['login'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$lastname = $_POST['email'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO client(client_login, client_name, client_lastname, client_email, client_password) VALUES (
    '".$login."',
    '".$name."',
    '".$lastname."',
    '".$email."',
    '".$password."',
)", $link);
```

скрипт ajax

```
$(function() {
    $('.sign-up-form').submit(function(e) {
      var $form = $(this);
      $.ajax({
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        data: $form.serialize()
      }).done(function() {
        alert('success');
      }).fail(function() {
        alert('fail');
      });
      e.preventDefault(); 
    });
  });
```

В обраотчик данные поступают, но затем не добавляются в базу, с подключением вроде бы все впорядке, тк вытягивать с его помощью данные из бд получается.

Comment: Рекомендую перейти, как минимум, на `mysqli`

Comment: Называть поля таблицы с префиксом данной таблицы - излишне.

Answer (score 2):

У вас в запросе mysql_query лишняя запятая после '".$password."'